# Comparison of typed objects in generic class

Tags: c#, generics, types

Following code is given, i want to just compare two objects inside a generic class.

```
public bool Compare<T>()
    {
        T var1 = default(T);
        T var2 = default(T);        
        return var1 == var2;
        //Error CS0019  Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'
    }
```

Can anybody explain why it is not possible to compare these two objects in this generic class?

Comment: Is the `default(T)`  just as an example, or is that actually the case you want to compare? Else, I would say that it's just always `true`, as long as the implementer of a struct hasn't gone completely quirky with overriding `==`.

Answer (score 1):

The Type T is not necessarily a reference type, T is a type argument and can be a class or a struct, so the compiler will not be able to make that assumption.

You can do like

```
public bool Compare<T>()
{           
        T var1 = default(T);
        T var2 = default(T);

        return !EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(var1, var2);
}
```

You can also try to make T [`IComparable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) or else you can try to use an [`IComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) to your class.

Comment: This will use `Object.Equals` (and `Object.GetHashCode`) for `T`, unless `T : IEquatable<T>`, in which case it uses that.

Answer (score 0):

Quick option:

```
public bool Compare<T>()
{
    var t1 = default(T);
    var t2 = default(T);
    return object.Equals(t1, t2);
}
```

Generically correct option:

```
public bool Compare<T>()
{
    var t1 = default(T);
    var t2 = default(T);
    return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(t1, t2);
}
```

Be careful of the code below because if variable t1 is null you will receive an exception

```
public bool Compare<T>()
{
    var t1 = default(T);
    var t2 = default(T);
    return t1.Equals(t2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can´t use the `==`-operator on your Type `T` because there is no guarantee that this operator is defined on that type. Imagine `T` is of type `KeyValuePair` for example. You cannot write the following:

```
var areEqual = (new KeyValuePair<string, string>("1", "1") == new KeyValuePair<string, string>("2", "2"))
```

Make some constraint on your generic type such as `where T : new()` to allow only classes where the default-value is `null`.

EDIT: As a constraint on only classes is quite meaningless because reference-types allways default to `null` you can unbox your instance of `T` to `object` and then call the `==`-operator:

```
public bool Compare<T>()
{
    object var1 = default(T);
    object var2 = default(T);
    if (var1 == null) return var1 == var2;
    return var1.Equals(var2);
}
```

This allows you to call the method for both value- and reference-types.

Comment: What if var1 is null? It won't work

Comment: @MartinSwanepoel Good point, updated.

Comment: Still won't work `return var1 == var2;`

Comment: @MartinSwanepoel ?? Sure, tested it some seconds ago. Leads to something similar to `return null == var2` which returns true if `var2` is also `null`, false otherwise. Or do I miss anything?